# Configure Visual Studio Team Services Pull Request to require Git Rebase

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request, tfs-code-review

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio Team Services Pull Request to require a Branch be Rebased?  In other words, fail the PR if a Fast-Forward is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t this feature included in VSTS pull request. I submitted a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17126716-vsts-git-pull-request-policy), you can vote it.